# Pass list of lists of list to function

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have values in a list of lists.

I would like to send the whole block to a conversion function which then returns all the converted values in the same structure.

```
my_list = [sensor1...sensor4] = [hum1...hum3] = [value1, value2, value3, value4]
```

So several nested lists

```
def conversion(my_list): dictionaries
    for sensor in my_list:
        for hum in sensor:
            for value in hum:
                map(function, value)
```

Is there a way to do a list comprehension as a one liner? I'm not sure how to use the map function in comprehensions especially when you have several nested iterations.

Comment: ...what exactly do you think that first line is doing?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe psuedocode

Comment: It's not even pseudocode; why not provide a [mcve] that *actually shows what you're doing?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Comment: Isin't your list more like `[ [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ], [...] ]`

Comment: Wait. Function returns dictionary. Where is the dictionary ?

Comment: @FunkySayu That’s not valid syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
map(function, value)
```

Since you are just mapping a function on each value, *without* collecting the return value in a list, using a list comprehension is not a good idea. You *could* do it, but you would be collecting list items that have no value, for the sole purpose of throwing them away later—just so you can save a few lines that actually serve a much better purpose: Clearly telling what’s going on, without being in a single, long, and complicated line.

So my advice would be to keep it as it is. It makes more sense like that and clearly shows what’s going on.

> I am however collecting the values. They all need to be converted and saved in the same structure as they were.

In that case, you still don’t want a list comprehension as that would mean that you created *a new list* (for no real reason). Instead, just update the most-inner list. To do that, you need to change the way you’re iterating though:

```
for sensor in my_list:
    for hum in sensor:
        for i, value in enumerate(hum):
            hum[i] = map(function, value)
```

This will *update* the inner list.

Alternatively, since `value` is actually a list of values, you can also replace the `value` list’s *contents* using the slicing syntax:

```
for sensor in my_list:
    for hum in sensor:
        for value in hum:
            value[:] = map(function, value)
```

Also one final note: If you are using Python 3, remember that `map` returns a generator, so you need to convert it to a list first using `list(map(function, value))`; or use a list comprehension for that part with `[function(v) for v in value]`.

Comment: I am however collecting the values.  They all need to be converted and saved in the same structure as they were.  Which means in those nested for loops I need to pass everything back down the chain :S Efficient it ain't

Comment: Value is not a list, they are the actual floats needing converted with the function

Comment: @cc6g11 You should *really* get your question straight. It’s conflicting with what you are saying here. In your question, you seem to have a value list, and that also makes sense since you are calling `map` on it; you can’t call `map` on a single float.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to do it. You *can* use list comprehension to do that, but you shouldn't for code readability and because it's probably not faster.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ho... I learned something in english today. I mean readability